# How do i return the value of a css property of a style in the stylesheet using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am currently overriding a wordpress plugin javascript by using a 'top: 100px !important' element in the stylesheet.

However, depending on the scroll of the document, I need to change the 100px dynamically using javascript and jquery.

I would love to use the .css() method, but that is already currently being used by the plugin and I need to dynamically update the property value dependent on the scroll down length by the site visitor.

How do i do this the clean 2017 year way? :)

Comment: you can try with first removing the css by `$(".your-element").css("top","");` and then below add yours `$(".your-element").css("top,"your-css");`

Comment: can you show me that plugin which you added?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/sticky-menu-or-anything-on-scroll/

Comment: that wouldn't work, because it's using the .css class which only alters the inline element. I'm using the stylesheet with !important property to override the .css() method being used elsewhere from the plugin.

Comment: plugin works fine on a new website, but i'm doing this for a client, and client's website has some css/js conflict i can't seem to pinpoint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to dynamically remove the current value of that `"top"` property and then assign your new value for that `"top"` property dynamically.

Comment: how do i get the property of the specific style i'm targeting? I want to do something like $('div.hello#world').updateProperty('top': newValue + 'px')

Comment: is there easy jquery like code that can target elements in the <stylesheet> tag and change them easily? I'm also using setInterval so it will be updating frequently.. Sorry for aligning with spaghetti code, but i need to do this for now..

Answer (score 0):

try `$('#yourElm').css($('#yourElm').css('cssText')+'top:'+newValue+'px !important;');`

no need to get rid anything as other suggest, inline css have most priority, I think.